# AttributeError: Django Model has no attribute 'instructor_name'

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, attributeerror

Trying to figure out why I'm getting an attribute error here. I've done this same process before in the Django tutorial, but here, I'm getting an attribute error using the same logic.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.


class Department(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department_name


class Instructor(models.Model):
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    instructor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.instructor_name
```

Like the documentation tutorial for Django, I am attempting to have an empty query set outputted while I'm in my python shell. When I create and save the data into the database, I come back and assign the data to an object by using `d = Department.objects.get(pk=1)` I get the desired output as I can call upon `d.department_name` and it'll output the name I originally assigned it. When I call upon `d.instructor_name.all()` the same way the tutorial does for `q.choice_text.all()` I am not returned with an empty query set, but rather this error:

```
<ipython-input-18-29fd5cce7e1e> in <module>()
----> 1 d.instructor_name.all()

AttributeError: 'Department' object has no attribute 'instructor_name'
```

Not really sure what I'm doing differently here. I've read other posts with similar issues, but they're always doing something slightly different and I can't seem to apply what they learned to my issue.

Here's the tutorial for reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Try with

```
d.instructor_set.all()
```

Long answer:

The way django creates a reverse link between two models joined by a ForeignKey is by creating a new attribute in the model that does not have the ForeignKey (in this case Department). The attribute name is `model name in lowercase`_set

So, if you have a Department object *d*, the way to obtain all inspectors that belong to the department is

```
d.instructor_set.all()
```

Side note: I would argue that the names of your attributes caused the problem. Instead of "*department_name*" and "*instructor_name*" I would simply use "*name*", that way when you want to print the department name, just say "department.name" which is very readable.

Also d.inspector_name.all() would change to d.name.all(), which is easily detectable as an error.